# How to access View Template Properties for Revit and compare them in Real Time?

Tags: view, properties, autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit

I am trying to list the view template’s properties so we can compare them with another old template. 
For example what model elements are hidden or have overrides in a given template or which Revit links have been hidden or overridden in a given template.

[View Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/046V3.png)
(https://www.google.com/search?q=view+template+revit&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS770US770&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLndrd2cTbAhVESq0KHX1cAPwQ_AUICygC&biw=1536&bih=824#imgrc=Q0v-pV7Nxl4kfM:)

I’m looking to devise a View Template Compare tool and access to the owner and creator of them.

```
public void ApplyViewTemplateToActiveView()
{
    Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
    View viewTemplate = (from v in new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
        .OfClass(typeof(View))
        .Cast<View>()
        where v.IsTemplate == true && v.Name == "MyViewTemplate"
        select v)
        .First();
    using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc,"Set View Template"))
    {
        t.Start();           
        doc.ActiveView.ViewTemplateId = viewTemplate.Id;
        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

With Revit API you can access with: 
GetTemplateParameterIds Method / ViewTemplateId Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Yes, I guess you can use Forge Model Derivative API to export RVT file and then build a dashboard around the View Templates data. That's assuming that View Templates data actually gets exported when the model is translated. That data is not attached to any geometry so I would not be surprised if it was skipped. The question here is why? This is like renting a 16-wheel truck to move a duffel bag across the street.

No, if your intention is to directly interact with the RVT model. Forge can view it, but to push anything back or request changes to the model, is not available yet. Then again, I am not even sure that the view template data is available via model derivative exports.

This brings me another alternative. Why not just collect the data using Revit API, the standard way and then push it out to a Database and build on top of that? There is no reason to employ Forge for any of that.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for the great answer and explanation, I am totally agree with your answer, there is no need to involve forge in this task, it can be easily solved as you pointed out. Btw I am still curious if with Forge you can access to these specific data. Hope to find out more in the upcoming Forge Accelerator.

Comment: Konrad could be great to send these data and do the comparison in real time before the user sync in order to promptly prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

The Revit API exposes almost all the ViewTemplate properties.
For instance this method returns all the Visibility/Graphic Overrides for a specific category:

https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/ed267b82-56be-6e3b-0c6d-4de7df1ed312.htm

The only thing I couldn't get for a ViewTemplate are the "includes", but all the rest seems to be there.

**Update:**
The list or properties "not included" can be retrieved with `GetNonControlledTemplateParameterIds()`.

[image: includes]

Comment: Hi Teo thanks a lot, the main problem is to access the properties of the views of the Linked Models at the moment. Let see if they will open the API also for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeremy, I had dig into your amazing website and also some solution that Konrad post in the Dynamo Forum about this. In Revit seems pretty achievable, you filter the View that is View Template and then extracts these properties, is it correct?.
I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction with Forge.
Some amazing guys are developing a BQL https://www.retriever.works/.
BQL(Building Query Language) is a query language for buildings, similar to how SQL is a query language for databases. It is fast and flexible. BQL helps improve efficiency for QA/QC (quality assurance and quality control), and building data extraction without leaving Revit. I am also trying these and I would like to understand if there are some works where I could start with Forge next week about this.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Will be possible to do this with Forge?